# Aren't vectors protected from going out of bounds?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37852130/how-different-versions-of-c-differ-in-stl), and noticed a comment which said:

> Maybe you go out of bounds on one of the vectors?

I'm not asking about **indexing** with `[]` to an element which is out of bounds, which will obviously be out of bounds. And from what I can tell, that's not what the OP did. (I could be totally wrong.) I've not heard of any other cases for going out of bounds with `std::vector`.

I was taught vectors are protected from going out of bounds when using `.push_back(/*data*/)`. Due to the very high reputation of the commentor, I have little double that the comment comes from a depth of knowledge. The OP in that question uses `.push_back()`, which, again, I thought was a `std::vector` member function protected from going out of bounds.

Is there something important I should learn about `std::vector` in that regard which someone more expert than I in C++ can explain?

Comment: In the OP's code he's using `operator[]`, which might cause out of bounds trouble. Isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean "out of bounds using `push_back`"? The `push_back` is a writing operation, not reading. And it doesn't take an index, so how would bounds come into play in any way?

Comment: `v[x].push_back(make_pair(y,d));`, @JoachimPileborg is probably talking about the `v[x]`, not the `.push_back(...)`.

Comment: @songyuanyao I suppose that could be... since he is using `v[x].push_back(/*data*/)`... accessing the `x` element of the `std::vector`, then pushing back.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 Yes, so before `push_back`, `operator[]` will be called firstly and cause out of bound error.

Comment: @songyuanyao Ah... so yes, `[ ]` is the issue. I'd just not seen in used in combination with `.push_back()` before... Is it me, or does that seem not advisiable?

Comment: @NonCreature0714 The statement is fine itself, especially for a 2d vector.

Comment: It is a vector of vectors, so `v[x]` accesses vector x in the vector-of-vectors, and then `push_back` is called on that specific vector x. As far as "not advisable", it is no different than the general advisability of using `operator[]` for a vector. If you know for certain that you are within range, then it is fine.

Comment: @songyuanyao & Cody Grey, Thanks for clarifying. I was very confused.

Comment: Just a minor addition: Right one line above the one in question, there is `cin >> x;`  -- so x could be anything, even negative, depending on what the user (of the compiled program) enters. And as there is no range check for `x`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they're not *that* protected. C++ makes it *easy* to be correct:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for (int i : v) // cannot go out of bounds
```

but in general it cannot always prove up front that you're correct:

```
std::vector<int> v = something();
int i = v[v[0]]; // How would the compiler know if it's legal?
```

To make this safe regardsless of the contents of `v`, you can write

```
int i = v.at(v.at(0)); // might throw at runtime
```

but this is slower because of the additional runtime check.

Answer (score 1):

Some `vector` methods have bounds checking, but not all.

Bounds-checked operations (throw `std::out_of_range` for invalid indexes):

- `at`

Non-checked operations (exhibit undefined behaviour for invalid indexes):

- `operator[]`

Any use of an iterator requires that the iterator be valid (or, in some cases, be the 'end' iterator):

- `erase`
- `emplace`

Some methods require a precondition (and exhibit undefined behaviour if the vector is empty):

- `front`
- `back`
- `pop_back`

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is made to be used just like an array, hence index operator doesn't have checks for performance reasons. In Debug builds, they may have asserts to find out bugs. But such checks don't exist in Release build. This way compiler can optimize **away** the function call itself, and put the array access at the call site. Accessing elements out of bounds is undefined behaviour, and one should use `vector::at` (performance cost!)

`push_back` may throw a runtime exception (`bad_alloc` by the default allocator).